# I don't understand another user's unofficial solution to Problem 49, Chapter 4, in Blitzstein and Hwang's Introduction to Probability (2019 2e).

Tags: probability, expected-value

I don't understand [Quasar](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/247892/quasar)'s [unofficial solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4349956). The public student solution manual doesn't solve this exercise.

My problem concerns $P(A_j)$. I would have done $\dfrac{\binom{n}{1}\binom{n-1}{k-1}}{\binom{n}{k}}$, which would be $k$, so I understand the final answer is wrong.  But why isn't $P(A_j) = \dfrac{\binom{n}{1}\binom{n-1}{k-1}}{\binom{n}{k}}$?

Comment: You have two groups of prices: Group 1 with a size of 1 and you choose this price j. The corresponding binomial coefficient is $\binom{1}1$. And you have another group 2, which is not price j. From the $n-1$ remaining prizes you choose $k-1$. The corresponding binomial coefficient is $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$

Comment: If your question has been answered, please mark the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be the set of $n$ prizes. You want to know the probability that some value $j$ is contained in a random subset of $k$ elements of $A$.

You can do this assuming $j$ is selected. This results in you getting $j$ *and* another $k - 1$ values of $A$. Therefore, there are $\binom{1}{1}\binom{n-1}{k-1} = \binom{n-1}{k-1}$ sets of $k$ elements containing $j$.

If there are $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ sets that have $j$, then the probability of getting a set that contains $j$ is $\frac{\binom{n-1}{k-1}}{\binom{n}{k}} = \frac{k}{n}$.

The rest is simply applying the definition of expected value.